# Should separate tags that differentiate between service packs that have no core changes exist?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm not talking about general version changes (e.g., [language-v1] -> [language-v2]) but specifically between updates that are nothing but bug and performance fixes.

In particular, I'm talking about tags that have different ones per "service pack:"

[.net-3.5](/questions/tagged/.net-3.5) (**x3609**) [.net-3.5-sp1](/questions/tagged/.net-3.5-sp1) (**x120**)

[asp.net-3.5](/questions/tagged/asp.net-3.5) (**x708**) [asp.net-3.5sp1](/questions/tagged/asp.net-3.5sp1) (**x26**)

[visual-studio-2008](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2008) (**x10745**) [visual-studio-2008-sp1](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2008-sp1) (**x161**)

And to a lesser extent:

[visual-studio-2010](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2010) (**x11021**) [visual-studio-2010-sp1](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2010-sp1) (**x46**)

Tags also exist for Windows XP *but* there have been major core changes between those versions so they do not apply here.

As I understand, changes between .NET 3.5 and SP1 (also applies to ASP.NET and Visual Studio 2008 by extension) [are primarily just fixes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951847) [and performance improvements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383815%28VS.90%29.aspx) and there isn't much changes in *how* the frameworks/tools are used.  The only breaking change that I know of (that is worth mentioning) is how [`Enumerable.Cast<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) no longer performs conversions.

Changes between Visual Studio 2010 and SP1 are not that significant to me to warrant the distinction (or at least, I'm just not as familiar with the changes to fully understand how different they really are).  [I can see possible need for distinction here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509) as there might be questions based on the additions this service pack introduced (including but not limited to Silverlight 4, HTML 5, etc.) but perhaps someone else who is more familiar with them could clarify.

If there are other core changes that I am not aware of, then please share them.

Should this distinction exist?  The 307+ questions that use these tags could get more eyes on their questions without a problem IMHO.  Otherwise, how often are problems about the specific changes going to come up?  Not enough to deem these tags necessary IMHO.

What do you think?

Comment: Hmm. There *are* significant changes between VS 2008 RTM and SP1, and VS 2010 RTM and SP1. Specifically, there are the type of changes that cause subtle bugs and changes in behavior, which are the type of questions that get asked on SO. People who have had trouble with the service pack should probably tag their question with the appropriate version of the service pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cody answered in his comment: yes for Visual Studio (major changes), no for .NET framework.

I instituted that change.

As for philosophy of version tags, *they should generally be avoided altogether*, except in the case where you have a strong and compelling reason to believe your question will only ever be relevant to one particular version of whatever the heck it is you are asking about.